# SharePoint create anonymous share link

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, postman

I have the following problem: I need to upload images massively in vtex. For this I need a link so that vtex can read it.

These images are in SharePoint, the problem is that consulting the Rest API in Postman .

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TIDIGITAL/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/carpet/100012.jpg')/ListItemAllFields/GetSharingInformation
```

and consulting the `directURL` field returns the image, but to access it, I must log in, which does not work for me in vtex.

I need to create an anonymous link to the image or an alternative solution to be able to perform this task.

I don't see information about it in Microsoft's documentation. I tried to make a post call to

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TIDIGITAL/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/carpet/100012.jpg')/ListItemAllFields/sharelink
```

but I get the following error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException
> Cannot find resource for the request sharelink.